# Variadic class template and variadic constructor

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++17

[On C++ weekly ep. 48 by Jason Turner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gNzhE-Tn40) there is the following code:

```
template<typename ... B>
struct Merged : B...
{
  template <typename ... T>
  Merged(T && ... t) : B(std::forward<T>(t))...
  {  }

  using B::operator()...;
};
```

It fails with the following on gcc 7.1:

```
error: mismatched argument pack lengths while expanding 'B'
```

What is the proper way to Expand B?

(BTW, in the above link, the code seems to compile with some 7.0 snapshot).

Edit1:

As noted by @Jarod42, it will compile with Structs acting as the functors. The actual video use lambda and it seems to break there.

```
auto l1 = [] { return 4 ; };
auto l2 = [](const int i) { return i * 10; };
// This would work, S1, S2 are just functors structs
Merged<S1, S2> merged1(42, "hello");
// This fails
Merged merged2 = Merged(l1, l2);
```

Edit2:

Seems like User-defined deduction guides does not work here.

```
template <typename ... T>
Merged(T...) -> Merged<std::decay_t<T>...>;
```

The above should have enable the following:

```
Merged merged(l1, l2);
```

But it does not. It seems like you have to pass the types to Merged<>

```
Merged<t1, t2> merged(l1, l2);
```

which probably not really what the tutorial wanted to demonstrate.

Comment: isnt that c++17 and not c++11 ? At least I get [quite different errors when compiling with c++11](http://ideone.com/Pd4tRO)

Comment: I suppose that you have provided the wrong number of parameters to the constructor?

Comment: Works [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5bdcaecb54f760c2).

Comment: @Jarod42 - yes, clang would take it. Gcc would not.BTW - This has nothing to do with wrong number of params. And yes - as the video suggests, I'm using c++1z.

Comment: @Kobi: I commented clang in fact (bad c++1z error unrelated to code). and gcc accepts it.

Comment: @tobi303: `using B::operator()...;` is legal only in C++1z.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like there is no need to have any constructor defined here, and instead, just using C++17 aggregate:

```
template<typename ... B>
struct Merged : B...
{
//  This is not needed, it would actually render this class
//  to be a non-aggregate one.
//  template <typename ... T>
//  Merged(T && ... t) : B(std::forward<T>(t))...
//  {  }

    using B::operator()...;
};

// C++17 class deduction guidance (user defined)
template <typename ... T>
Merged(T...) -> Merged<T...>;

int main()
{
    auto l1 = [] { return 4 ; };
    auto l2 = [](const int i) { return i * 10; };
    // Note here, using {} for initializing an aggregate
    Merged merged{l1, l2};
}
```

Note the C++17 class deduction user defined guidance, plus using {} for initializing an aggregate.

Constructor is not needed. If we had it, this class would not be an aggregate anymore and the syntax used for initializing, would stop working.

Answer (score 2):

If the sizes of the parameter packs should be equal, we can enforce this with `std::enable_if`:

```
template<typename ... B>
struct Merged : B...
{
  template <typename ... T,
            typename = typename std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(T) == sizeof...(B)>>
  Merged(T && ... t) : B(std::forward<T>(t))...
  {  }

  using B::operator()...;
};
```

This together with the user-defined deduction guide [seems to work](https://godbolt.org/z/4csad5).

Answer (score 1):

With

```
template <typename ... T>
Merged(T&& ... t) : B(std::forward<T>(t))...
{}
```

`sizeof...(T)` should be equal to `sizeof...(B)`:
You have to provide one argument by base.

And then it [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5bdcaecb54f760c2).

If you don't provide same number of argument, you hace error similar to:

> error: mismatched argument pack lengths while expanding 'B'

Comment: OK @Jarod42 . Seems like the issue comes from the lambda part. [this](https://godbolt.org/g/VFRzV8) does not work. The link will be very close to the actual code in the video.

Comment: It seems it is the auto type deduction which fails, see [modified example with lambda](https://godbolt.org/g/Nfs4Ph)

Comment: BTW - it does mean that C++17 deduction guide feature is not working. The whole idea was to use this and not pass the template params explicitly.

Comment: @Kobi use a deduction guide that removes references.